# Exclude string using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have some emails

```
info@gmail.com
epd@omi.ru
salesall@finteca.ru
```

I need to ignore strings that contain `info, sales`, so I used pattern:

```
'/(?!spb)[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-z0-9\.]+$'
```

But it returns `[]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the code you're trying to use. What do you want to exclude them from? A list, a dict, a set?

Comment: @AustinHastings I specify this data in my question. I tried to test that in sample with email. And to do that I use `emails = re.findall(pattern, test)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/505NB9/3

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?m)^(?!.*(?:info|sales))\S+@\S+\.\S+$', s)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more understandable and maintainable:

```
import re

string = """
info@gmail.com
epd@omi.ru
salesall@finteca.ru

some other text here with emails email@email.com included"""

rx = re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')

def ignore(value):
  lst = ['info', 'sales']
  for i in lst:
    if i in value:
      return False
  return True

emails = filter(ignore, rx.findall(string))
print(emails)
# ['epd@omi.ru', 'email@email.com']
```

Simply adjust the `lst` of `ignore()` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/505NB9/1 It looks like the first two chars are not needed.

Comment: I think no. because it light string, that not match pattern

Comment: Yes sorry i did not understand the the question. You could avoid regex though:
`if 'info' in email.split('@')[0] or 'sales' in email.split('@')[0]:`

Answer (score 0):

See my working example below.

- For your code to work properly you will need to include `^`to indicate the start of a line as well.
- The reason you got `[]` is probably because you didn't use the re.MULTILINE option. The re.MULTILINE flag tells python to make the ‘^’ and ‘$’ special characters match the start or end of any line within a string, as opposed to the start or end of the entire string.

[image: Visual representation of the required regular expression]

```
import re

test = 'info@gmail.com\nepd@omi.ru\nsalesall@finteca.ru'
print(test)

info@gmail.com
epd@omi.ru
salesall@finteca.ru

pattern = re.compile('^(?!info|sales)[[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-z0-9.]+$', re.MULTILINE)
emails = re.findall(pattern, test)
print(emails)

['epd@omi.ru']
```